# Is BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputstream different from InputStream and Outputstream

Tags: java, android, inputstream

recently i had troubles working with InputStreams and OutputStreams when  i was trying to implement a basic file downloader in my android application.. to elaborate things this is how i did it..

i get an InputStream object using the apache HttpClient classes then tried writing the stream to a file.. but strangely when i buffer the InputStream or the OutputStream i get an unreadable file.... this is the code..

//to make the code concise i removed exceptions and stream closing..

```
private void download(InputStream in,String fileName){   

//if i dont use the buffered thing and read directly from in everything is ok
// same is the buffered out i had to use in/outstream 
BufferedInputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(in);  
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));  

BufferedOutputstream  bufferedOut = new BufferedOutputstream(fout);    
int read = -1;

while((read = bufferedIn.read()) != -1){
   bufferedOut.write(read);
}
//close the buffers
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by unreadable ? Really unreadable ? Truncated result ? Empty file ? Beware to really close the files explicitly at the end! They are `Buffered*Stream`s so not closing them may lead to un`flush`ed writes at the end...

Comment: You need to `flush` your buffer. That takes all residual data left in the buffer and writes it to your stream.

Comment: Are you sure that your code is correct ? You read into `buffered` not into `bufferedIn`. It seems that you oversimplified your code... Please give us the original code. Are you really closing `BufferedOutputStream` ?

Comment: i did close it do i need to flush it??

Answer (score 2):

You have to flush the buffered outputstream when you're done with it.

Comment: Flush ... or close.  Generally speaking, close is better, because that deals with resource leaks as well.

Answer (score 2):

In any case you probably want to `flush()` your output (done implicitly by `close()`), but with `BufferedOutputStream` this is even more important than with a other `OutputStream`s. If you have a `FileOutputStream`, the only buffering performed is that of the OS. If you have a `BufferedOutputStream`, Java performs its own buffering on top of it.

If you use Java 7 or newer, I'd recommend to write the code like this:

```
try (BufferedInputStream bIn = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    BufferedOutputStream bOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) {
    for (int read; ((read = bIn.read()) != -1; )
        bOut.write(read);
}
```

In your case I suspect you were closing the `FileOutputStream` but not the `BufferedOutputStream`. Therefore the file was truncated or even empty because the data buffered in the `BufferedOutputStream` was not flushed.

Comment: can i use java 7 for android.. am on linux with openJdk 6 i closed all the streams... its a word document

Comment: You can - and should - use Java 7 for Android.